# How can you export a file from your phonegap application to a pc?

Tags: cordova, export

I am working on a simple data collection tool using PhoneGap and KnockoutJS, which allows a user to collect some data, store it, and then report on it on the phone.

However the reports are nice on the phone but in reality they will want to print off these reports and export the data for use in Excel or some other program.

So is there a way to bluetooth/usb a file to a computer from inside your application or any other way to achieve this? As ideally I want the user to be able to click an export button within the application and without exiting somehow get the file onto the computer...

I thought that maybe I would need to create a windows application and maybe use a tcp/bluetooth/other to connect from the phone app to the desktop app and then stream the data over, but would rather not have to write another application if a way already exists (which I doubt it will)

I would even find it acceptable at the moment to just build a file and output it to somewhere on the local device and just tell the user to copy it to their computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use the internet for sending the file?

You could send an email.
Upload the file to some cloud storage and send the url for download as an email.

Properly most users don`t want to fiddle with bluetooth, if you can just easily send an email.

Comment: Thats a good idea, send the file as an email from the machine to the other one... will leave the question open a while longer incase anyone else comes up with another good solution.